# Do you really "see someone about something"?

Tags: expressions, british-english

> I've got to see my GP about vaccinations for my trip.

It's a sentence written by a British English native speaker.

1. Is it grammatically correct or it's just brachylogy?
2. Is "to see sb about sth" a common expression or it's only used in a medical context? Can I say e.g. "I need to see my mum about Crimbo" (meaning "I need to see and talk to her about organising Christmas")?
3. Is it likely to be said by non-British English native speakers?

Comment: You may be interested in this: [see a man about a dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/See_a_man_about_a_dog)

Comment: A number of (presumably, *American*) writers have used *[I'll have to] [see the president about that*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22see+the+president+about+that%22), so it's obviously not peculiar to the *British*.

Comment: It's a very common usage. I too immediately thought of _see a man about a dog_.

Comment: But one (now rather dated) usage that probably ***is*** peculiarly British is ***I've got to see a man about a dog*** (I need to go to the lavatory). Where Americans would say ***I need to go to the bathroom*** (regardless of whether there's even a ***tap*** in the toilet, let alone a ***bath**!* :)

Comment: @KateBunting: ditto!

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - **I'm leaving now and I don't want to say why.**

Answer (score 1):

This is a common expression. It is certainly said by native speakers, at least in the UK. This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=see%20somebody%20about%20something&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csee%20somebody%20about%20something%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csee%20somebody%20about%20something%3B%2Cc0) search helps one to see the far-reaching scope of the expression.

[image]